# Problema ao instalar Gulp

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal, gulp, gulpjs

Estou tentando instalar o Gulp no Ubuntu, mas ele só me retorna erro:

```
root@gabriel-Aspire-E1-571:/var/www/aaa/projeto# npm install --save-dev gulp
npm WARN package.json projeto@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json projeto@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json projeto@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN engine gulp@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.9"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.13.4"})
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-41-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.4
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: vinyl-fs@'>=0.3.0 <0.4.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.1.0","1.0.0"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'gulp'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/aaa/projeto/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual a versão do NodeJs ?

Caso não seja 0.12.x recomendo atualizar!

Você instalou o Gulp de maneira global ?

**npm install -g gulp**

Comment: O problema era a versão do Node que não era a estavel